# WhatsApp messages not delivering

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am using Micromax Bolt A064. When I send some message in WhatsApp either in a group or for a single contact, it is just showing a clock symbol and not delivering.

I am using **WiFi** and I am able to receive hundreds of messages successfully. I can change the display picture & status without any issue.

This issue started once **I sent some 10 messages to 10 groups at a time**, is that the reason?

Comment: Backup your messages then clear data and cache of WhatsApp messenger

Comment: Thhanks buddy @esQmo

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to say that I have the exact same problem and found a much simpler but slow solution.

Like OP, I also sent a bunch of messages to a bunch of groups. Every other answer gives the same solution: Reinstall WhatsApp.

I then figure something out. We both have sent multiple messages to multiple groups. So maybe WhatsApp is still trying to send those messages and I cannot send any other messages until what I send is there.

Solution? I just sleep. The next day the problem is solved. No need to reinstall WhatsApp. Just sleep. Put my HP on a WiFi connection. Just wait. WhatsApp is sending all those messages to thousands of people. Once done. It's done.

Update: The solution is not good enough. Yes, eventually it works. But now WhatsApp delays my messages again. I do not mass send messages anymore. It seems that this is either a bug or a feature.

---

Symptoms:

WhatsApp Web says:

> Phone not connected. Make sure your phone has an active internet connection.

Any message sent is delayed. There is a clock If I try to send messages via phone, the message is not sent. It's as if my phone is not connected to the internet. It is.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Reinstalling WhatsApp solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

By uninstalling and reinstalling the app, the issue was fixed.
This issue may be because of poor internet, I tried to send 15-20 messages to 9-10 groups.....

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the data of WhatsApp and re-verify it.